# Find ratio within the grouped data in DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, spark-streaming

Here is the data frame - basically, there are two possible types - `X` and `Y` for different sources `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`...

```
Source | Type
-------------------
  A    |  X
  A    |  Y
  B    |  X
  C    |  Y
  A    |  X
  D    |  Y
 ...   | ...
```

The ultimate goal is to gather percentage ratio: `ratio(X in A) = count(X) / (count(X) + count(Y))`

So, in our example, `ratio(X in A) = 2 / (2 + 1) = 2 / 3 ~ 0.667`

Very simple, but I can't get how to do this in **one select** using only Streaming API v2 (Structured streaming, Dataframes)? 
From my perspective it's feasible only through the `map` functions...

This is what I have now - scattered counts for `X` and `Y` types

```
        msgDataFrame
                .select(SOURCE, TYPE)
                .where(msgDataFrame.col(TYPE).equalTo("X"))
                .groupBy(SOURCE)
                .count()
                .show(); // <-- gives me count for 'X'-es

        msgDataFrame
                .select(SOURCE, TYPE)
                .filter(msgDataFrame.col(TYPE).equalTo("Y"))
                .groupBy(SOURCE)
                .count()
                .show(); // <-- gives me count for 'Y'-cs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
msgDataFrame
.select("SOURCE", "TYPE")
.groupBy("SOURCE").pivot("TYPE", Seq("X", "Y")).agg(count(col("TYPE")))
.withColumn("Ratio", col("X") / (col("X") + col("Y")))
.show
```